# Failed to load Main-Class manifest Lucene Spellchecker

Tags: java, lucene, manifest, javac

I'm building a spellchecker using Lucene and getting a

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
/lib/lucene-spellchecker-2.3.2.jar
```

That file is in the right path a la:

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked -cp lib/lucene-core-2.9.0.jar;lib/lucene-spellchecker-2.3.2.jar -source 1.5 -target 1.5 \
  -d bin/ `find src/ -name *.java`
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You might think about using Ant to invoke your compiler instead of `find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're on a Unix system so you need to use `:` instead of `;` for your path separator.

Comment: If I do so I get cannot find constructor SpellChecker(java.io.File). Does that mean there's something wrong with the code or with the path?

Comment: It looks like `SpellChecker` takes `Directory` in its only constructor, so it's probably your code. You can use `FSDirectory.open(File)` to get an instance with your `File`.